# When to use lazy evaluation in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation

I'm writing a module in C# which is a "sync" process that retrieves data from an external system, compares it with what's already in the DB and then updates the DB. Several entities are involved at once and the matching process is not simple, and involves lots of shuffling and filtering stuff between lists.

After a failed attempt at an OO implementation, I redesigned it with all the entity classes immutable and used a "functional" style with a lot of lambda expressions. I found it was very well suited to the problem domain and the code was much more readable. However, when I'm running it through in the debugger I'm finding it quite scary and worrying about side effects - For instance, I construct an IEnumerable of objects returned from the database, but they aren't physically retrieved until I enumerate the list, by which time the database might have been updated.

I realize that retrieving an object from the database isn't a pure functional operation, but I was hoping I could write cleaner code by treating it as if it was.

My instinct is to pepper the code with "ToList()" which it seems would solve the problem (and would also get rid of resharper's "possible multiple enumeration" warnings), but this seems a bit like cheating.

I've read stuff on lazy evaluation but mostly they are explaining the concepts in the context of pure functional code, and I don't see anything about the caveats of how to use it when external dependencies are involved.

In a non-trivial codebase, is there a simple way to decide where lazy evaluation might be harmful? or a better way to address the problems caused by functions with side effects?

Comment: Usually functional programming with side effects is done with monads. I don't know whether C# supports monads however.

Comment: This seems more suited for softwareengineering.stackexchange

Comment: When you expect large amount of data then  lazy evaluation is helpful. In case of working with database where you are going to run select causes with many filter go Iqueryable.

Comment: Allowing each class to go to the db by going through an Enumerable might cause performance issues. Consider using a Repository which returns your Enumerable.ToList(). Your db access is then limited to the Repository.

Comment: This question is silly. What dose lazy evaluation have to do with loading data in memory or reading it from db. You can use any load strategy with yield keyword.

Comment: Sometimes when you lazy up all these things, you end up with a scenario where everything happens all at once. If network communications is a feature of any of these dependencies, then you might end up with a situation where performance degrades _significantly_.

Answer (score 0):

When to use lazy evaluation?

1. Use it to defer evaluation/instantiation of something to when that object will actually be used, typically when there is a cost to the evaluation/instantiation and the object may not be used at all.
2. Use it to reduce the cost to extract the first M items of a set of size N where N >> M. Using iterators, you only incur the cost to retrieve/generate N items, rather than all M items first, then selecting the first N.

In your case, it seems that you need to retrieve your database object before any clients use it because you want the data accessed by all clients to be consistent/identical. In that case, it means you either evaluate your Enumerable before distributing it or distribute it in such a manner that after the first time it's evaluated, all other clients that do so will access the same data.

Comment: so in this case, you wouldn't consider putting a lot of ToList() to be a code smell ?

Comment: @Andy To have more than one `ToList()` would require you to do option 2 (distribute your Enumerable in such a manner that the first time it's evaluated, all other clients that do so will access the same data). In which case, you'd be providing a special implementation of `ToList()`. I'd just name whatever method you're providing something else, so when someone sees `ToAndy()` they know something special is happening.